# Pass variable values from a different page on a click event (VB.net)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

How can i pass the value of two variables into a click event in my ASP.net forms application.

i have 2 varaibles:

DocNo & Prefix which i need the values of in the click event, i am new to this i know i obviously cannot use ByVal which is used further down the document,

here is my code block in which i need to pass the varaibles into,

```
If Settings.IsCountryMode("USA") Then
                Script = "ShowPrintJobQuestionModal('" & Prefix & "', '" & DocNo & "', " & PrintDLG & ", " & Reprint & ", '" & ScrollBars & "');"
                'Redriects to a page in a new separate window
                'CreateOutput(AutoworkDocument.dt.job, Assign, AWDLineNo)
            Else
                General.RunJava(Me, General.OutputDoc("^", "", , , , , , False), "MultiDoc")
            End If

            RunJava(Script)
```

Comment: @K.K.Agarwal i am trying to find out how to pass the values of DocNo and Prefix into that Sub, the rest of the Subs uses ByVal to get the values, i cannot do this on this click event

Comment: Any error you are getting in your code?

Comment: No error the variables just are not receiving the correct values as they are just delcared as empty strings, i do not know how to pass the values i need,

Comment: first assign the value in the  variable then check it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now resolved,

```
Dim awd As AutoworkDocument
  awd = New AutoworkDocument()
  awd.loadSes()

  jobNo = awd.DocNum

If Settings.IsCountryMode("USA") Then
  Script = "ShowPrintJobQuestionModal('" & Prefix & "', '" & jobNo & "', " & PrintDLG & ", " & Reprint & ", '" & ScrollBars & "');"

 Else
 General.RunJava(Me, General.OutputDoc("^", "", , , , , , False), "MultiDoc")
 End If

RunJava(Script)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question...

Set the variable as public in your other class/form and use it:

```
COtherClassName.DocNo
```

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work  Dim Prefix As String
        Prefix = AutoworkDocument.GetDocumentPrefix(Prefix)

Comment: getdocumentprefix is the name of the function that returns the prefix i need

Comment: Dim isn't public. Create the variable as a member variable of the class: Public Prefix As String, then you can use it outside of the class: COtherClassName.Prefix

Comment: Thanks, i have now hard coded prefix which is ok however docnum i need, i have tried this code and i am now getting object reference not set to instance of an object Dim awd As AutoworkDocument
        Dim DocNo As String = String.Empty

        DocNo = awd.DocNum

Comment: awd.DocNum won't work unless DocNum is public in the AutoworkDocument class.